# System.Web.Routing only working with a .aspx file extension

Tags: iis-7, routes, asp.net-mvc-4

I have an application, that uses `System.Web.Routing` and it works great on all my environments. The only issue is, that my staging environment needs the ".aspx" at the end or I will get a 404. All other environments do not require it. They all run in Classic for the Managed Pipeline Mode with v4.0 .NET framework. I keep comparing IIS settings, but I can't find any differences. I've even compared `web.config` and `machine.config`, but no differences there either. Anybody know what it could be?

Comment: Routing or Url Rewriting?  Can we see code or web.config contents, please?

Comment: Routing, here's the global file http://pastebin.com/h0wbwNYZ

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you have this in your web.config (and normally you do want Integrated, unless you can't for some reason and [jump through the hoops so it works under Classic](http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/older-versions/deployment/using-asp-net-mvc-with-different-versions-of-iis-cs)).

```
  <system.webServer>
    <!-- omitted for brevity -->
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"/>
  </system.webServer>
```

`runaAllManagedModulesForAllRequests` has gotten me a couple times in the past.

Comment: Yeah, I have to use Classic. It works on most environments with classic though.