# Decimals resolving as files in ASP.Net MVC route on IIS7

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, iis-7

I'm having a problem where my the final decimal in my url string is being resolved to a file instead of being read as a decimal.

This is only happening on our production servers on II7.0 (so the wildcard map for aspnet_isapi.dll doesn't apply) and then only one of two production nodes.  The nodes are separated by a load balancer.

The url looks like:

```
http://innerwebz_node_1/12345/123.4
```

If I put in the url into the first node it works, on the second node it dies.

We've tried:

[Routing on IIS6 With Decimal In Route](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7530827/routing-on-iis6-with-decimal-in-route)

[System.Web.Routing only working with a .aspx file extension](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11018420/system-web-routing-only-working-with-a-aspx-file-extension)

The code base and configuration are identical except for node-specific settings.

Have you encountered anything like this?  Any clues or options to solve this would be helpful.

Comment: If it's only happening on one server, then it definitely sounds like an IIS configuration issue. Check to make sure each server has the exact same handler mappings.

Comment: They do as far as I can tell, but there are lots of configurations available so it's a needle in a haystack.  My guess is it's an IIS or machine config thing, but I've yet to find anything.